# How to create a table from POJO in android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing an android app where I have a java class which should represent a Table in DB.

```
class Table1 {
  String row1;
  String row2;
}
```

If I have to create a table in database I should do something like this.
`mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table1(row1 VARCHAR,row2 VARCHAR);");`

But the problem here is I'm duplicating the class structure in the SQL query. This is error prone and will require changes at multiple places whenever I need to change the attributes of the table. Is there a better way to do this. Something like `mydatabase.createTableFrom(Table1.class)` that I could use instead?

Comment: did you find any solution for it?

Comment: I think it's funny that nobody's done this. Use class name as tablename, add all variables as fields in the table. Map variable java types to sqlite types. Little of reflection. I'd make a prototype if I had time...